# Sending Email via IIS SMTP to external address

Tags: asp.net, iis, smtp

When using the following code to send an email message to an external e-mail address via IIS6 SMTP I am receiving a message stating that the message has been sent, but it never arrives at the destination.  I'm using the System.Net.Mail namespace and the following code:

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.From = new MailAddress(from);

foreach (string strTo in to.Split(';'))
{
  if (strTo.Replace(";", "") != string.Empty)
    msgMailSummary.To.Add(new MailAddress(strTo.Replace(";", "")));
}
msg.Subject = subject;
msg.Body = body;

SmtpClient sm = new SmtpClient();
sm.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
sm.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(tbUsername.Text, tbPassword.Text);
sm.Host = host;
sm.Port = port;
sm.Send(msg);
```

I don't have a SmartHost setup in IIS6, is there any obvious or any hints,tips that I can check out to get this working?

Comment: If you take a look at the pickup directory, are your emails still in there?

Comment: The e-mails are not being left inside the pickup directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was the setup on the server wasn't configured correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Umm, you seem to be missing one key line...

```
msg.To = new MailAddress(to);
```

Comment: That would be embaressing!  Got carried away stripping out all my code before posting, the code has this line:
foreach (string strTo in to.Split(';'))
{
    if (strTo.Replace(";", "") != string.Empty)
        msgMailSummary.To.Add(new MailAddress(strTo.Replace(";", "")));
}
Any new suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I remember right, but I once had a problem where I couldn't send an email because my From address was not what my hosting allowed. Basically I ended up being able to only set ReplyTo and leaving From undefined (the smtp server will define it by itself). Try it, it might work.

Comment: I'll check it out tomorrow and let you know!

Comment: I tried removing the FROM address undefined but I receive and error saying that the From address is missing...